# Object oriented design, define relationship

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am getting really confused about OOD when designing relatively large system. Always, we talk about has-a relationship between two entities. My question is about which one owns the other?

1. when designing a parking lot, there are many parking space. Should the car has an data field called parking space, or should the parking space hold the car? or both?
2. in a library reservation system, I am assuming there is a class Library, a class Book, and a class User. Shall the user call checkout(book), or the book call checkout(user), or the library call checkout(book, user)?

It's been very confusing for me. Any comment/suggestion is welcomed.

Lily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the situation, and what you mean by "own".

In your first example there is a one-one relationship between a car and a parking space. From a database perspective you will have to make a judgement about which should "own" the other (which table 'owns' the foreign key). You would base this judgement on expected usage - for example - since a parking space is likely to remain fixed, but you have cars coming and going all the time, it might make more logical sense for the carpark to "own" the car. That's where your design skills come into play.

In the second example, it seems to me that a single book can only be checked out to one user at a time, and "checking out" is an action that occurs on a book. Therefore the correct solution is `Book.checkout(user)`. Building on that, a user is likely to checkout more than one book at a time, so I would be inclined to do have a checkout method on Library, such that `Library.checkout(Books[], user)` called `Book.checkout(user)` in turn.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, the parking space should keep a record of if it is occupied and if so, what car is in it. Otherwise to see if you could park somewhere, you would have to poll every car to see if they are in that spot.

My immediate thinking for #2 is that it should be `Library.checkout(Book, User)` such that you make a note that a User has checked out a specific book.

This is heavily dependent on what you're trying to do however, and you should design it in such a way that is easiest for the problem at hand.

Sometimes replicating the data in two places isn't a terrible idea as long as you keep it synchronized. For instance, if you need to know where a specific car is parked, you're going to end up wanting to keep track of that data in the `Car` class as well, otherwise you're going to have to poll every parking spot to know if that car is parked there.

Comment: Surely it is: librarian.checkout(book, user) ?

Comment: @WW, you mean Library contains a list of Librarian, and ideally, the operation should be made at the Library level, Library.checkout(Book, User) may call Libarian.checkout(Book, User);

Answer (score 0):

In Object Oriented design the object can be considered an entity. At this point you may use the Entity relationship modelling to better understand who has to own what.

When you design your model you shouldn’t care how you are going to implement it. I mean you shouldn’t think who is going to own what because this is another process of the design that is when you are going to convert your model to objects (that can be data table, XML, C# object ,…. ) :  only at this point against the relationship the entity got you can decide who has to own what(sometime even against the requirements  as I’ll show you later).
At the design time you must focus just on the requirements you have. In the case of the car and car parking you should think about :

How many park  car one can occupied ?

How many cars a park can host ?

What kind of answer has my system to answer ? EX:  as user I want know where a car is parked against its car plate number (in this case the previous answer would be wrong because if you let the park own the car you should iterate through the park to get what car is on it)

As you can see it really depends by you business requirements especially when you have “one-to-one” relationship(as in this case).

So I can suggest you to have a look at “Entity relationship Modelling” and stick to  its concept to better design you object model.

Answer (score 0):

1. In this case undoubtedly parking space should hold a car(it's called aggregation), because the relationship between car and parking space isn't permanent(different cars can be parked in the same parking place in the same day)
2. In this case, I think, the user wants to get a book, so the GUI of this system must have some button(or smht else) that user has to click to reserve a book. So, user calls a method `checkout(book)` of the system(object Library represents it) to check if the book is free(or available). Then the system(Library) checks whether the book wasn't reserved earlier by other user, so it calls method `Book.check()` for all instances of this book. In such solution every user account in the system should have a list of reserved books which method `Book.check()` uses.

Answer (score 0):

To think out of box, I don't think the examples you provided have a natural "has a" or "owns a" relationship, and there are more relationships than "has a" or "owns a". In my opinion, I'd like to use a loosely coupled relationship for your examples, in implementation perspective, I would use a map to describe and maintain this relationship, which means, for a parking lot and a car, I would put a map in the Parking class, and map its slots to cars, if we find a slot existing in the map, we know that slot is occupied, if not, it's a free slot, for me, it doesn't make much sense either saying car owns the slot or the slot owns the car; for the library example, the same thing, the book and its borrower are in a very loose relationship, I'd put a map in the Library class, and map the book to its borrower. And who's the guy really does the checkout action? it's either the library staff or the auto machine or simply the library, so we can have a library.checkout(user, books), and inside the method, put books and user into the map.

For the bonus, what is really a "has a" relationship scenario? not a man has a car, this is not really a "has a", even we have "has a" in the sentence (don't let the human language mislead you), this just means, inside the car's class, there is a String field called ownerName or ownerId, that's it. One example for a real "has a" relationship scenario is human has a heart or a car has an engine, which means, in the implementation, there is really a Heart class field inside the Human Class.

How beautiful the object oriented design is!